# What is the value of $f(1999)$?

Tags: algebra-precalculus

Let be a function $f \colon \Bbb R\to \Bbb R$ given from:

$$f(x)=x^3+\sqrt{x^6+1}+\frac{1}{x^3-\sqrt{x^6+1}}$$

What is the value of $f(1999)$?

To me, it immediately seemed strange that it was necessary to calculate $f(1999)$. With a calculator everything would come easy. Since this question concerns high school students I have done the rationalization of $\frac{1}{x^3-\sqrt{x^6+1}}$ and I have found something very interesting. In fact

$$\frac{1}{x^3-\sqrt{x^6+1}}=\frac{1}{x^3-\sqrt{x^6+1}}\cdot\frac{x^3+\sqrt{x^6+1}}{x^3+\sqrt{x^6+1}}=\frac{x^3+\sqrt{x^6+1}}{-1}$$

because $(x^3-\sqrt{x^6+1})(x^3+\sqrt{x^6+1})=-1$

Thus
$$f(x)=x^3+\sqrt{x^6+1}-x^3-\sqrt{x^6+1}=0$$
and $f(1999)=0$ because $f(x)=0, \forall x\in\Bbb R$. Is it correct?

Comment: Your use of "i.e." at the end is incorrect ("i.e." means "that is"; and $f(1999)=0$ is not the same, nor implies, $f(x)=0$ for all $x\in\mathbb{R}$); that should be "because", not "i.e.". Otherwise, yes, this looks correct.

Comment: @ArturoMagidin Thank you for your advice. changed!

Comment: It is right!!!!

Comment: This was not a 'soft-question', try to avoid misusing tags

Comment: https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=x%5E3%2Bsqrt%28x%5E6%2B1%29%2B1%2F%28x%5E3-sqrt%28x%5E6%2B1%29%29%2C+x%3D1999

Comment: @FShrike Thank you very much to delete a not important tag.

Comment: @LuisAlexandher How do you create the wolfram alpha link?

Comment: @Sebastiano in the wolfram application in the upper right part there is a share button, the link is created there

Comment: @LuisAlexandher Can't find it. :-(

Comment: @Sebastiano in the mobile app, just to the right of the "WolframAlpha" text

Comment: Does this answer your question? [transforming a specific equation](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2453716/transforming-a-specific-equation)

Comment: @AnneBauval The processes look the same but I was computing a function.

Comment: So is the duplicate (they were wrong to call it an "equation").

Comment: @AnneBauval I don't know.

Comment: I added 1 character to the answer less than 5 minutes ago and it says the answer edited.  Interesting.

Comment: @lonestudent Boohhh :-(

Comment: This is also not a question about mathematics education, I must suggest you avoid misusing tags again.

Comment: Sure looks god to me.  My first thought was the opposite of yours, that to add them I had to put them over a common divisor so $x^3 + \sqrt{x^6+1}=\frac {(x^3 + \sqrt{x^6+1})(x^3 - \sqrt{x^6+1})}{x^3 - \sqrt{x^6+1}}$ and we know $(a+b)(a-b) = a^2 - b^2$ so we get $\frac {(x^6) - (x^6+1)}{x^3 - \sqrt{x^6+1}}$ and... well, it just falls out from there....  Oh... now I see why you did it your way.  You wanted to deradicalize the denominator first.  Well, that works too. (key thing is the one term is the radical conjugate of the denominator of the other and so....)

Comment: @fleablood Thank you very much for your contribute.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your work seems correct to me. (this is stated in the comments that your work is correct)

The problem statement is essentially equivalent to:

> Let $f:\mathbb R\rightarrow \mathbb R$,
> $$f(x):=A(x)+B(x)+\frac {1}{A(x)-B(x)}$$
> where, $A^2(x)-B^2(x)=-1$.
> Find the value of $f(1999).$

$$
\begin{align}f(x):&=A(x)+B(x)+\frac{A(x)+B(x)}{A^2(x)-B^2(x)}\\
&=A(x)+B(x)-\left(A(x)+B(x)\right)\\
&=0~.\end{align}
$$

Thus $f(x)\equiv 0$, $\forall x\in\mathbb R$, since $\operatorname{dom}f=\mathbb R.$

What we do is based on using [conjugate](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conjugate_(square_roots)).

Note that, when you add fractions, the conjugate will appear by itself. Indeed,

$$
\begin{align}f(x):&=A(x)+B(x)+\frac {1}{A(x)-B(x)}\\
&=\frac {\left(A(x)-B(x)\right)\cdot\left(A(x)+B(x)\right)+1}{A(x)-B(x)}\\
&=\frac{\overbrace{A^2(x)-B^2(x)}^{\color {#c00}{-1}}+1}{A(x)-B(x)}\\
&=0~.
\end{align}
$$

Because, $A^2(x)-B^2(x)=-1$ implies that, $A(x)±B(x)≠0$.

Finally, I want to note that this type of function is called a [constant function](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Constant_function) in mathematics.

Comment: Wei hola'. Thank you very much.

Comment: Provided there are no instances in which $A(x)+B(x)=0$ while $A(x)-B(x)\neq 0$ (as is the case in the function at hand).

Comment: @ArturoMagidin Since $A^2(x)-B^2(x)=-1$, therefore we don't need these restrictions.

Comment: True.... ${}{}{}$